# How to attach geth to a local Parity RPC port 8545?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, parity

I'm running `parity` with the `--jsonrpc` flag which listens on port `8545` by default.

I'm trying to attach a `geth` instance, like [described in the the docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#attach):

> Attach a console to a running geth instance. By default this happens over IPC on the default IPC endpoint but when necessary a custom endpoint could be specified:
>
> ```
> geth attach                   # connect over IPC on default endpoint
> geth attach ipc:/some/path    # connect over IPC on custom endpoint
> geth attach http://host:8545  # connect over HTTP
> geth attach ws://host:8546    # connect over websocket
> ```

But I get a fatal error:

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - Invalid endpoint
```

This is my tested commands:

```
 ~ $ geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545
Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - Invalid endpoint
 ~ $ geth attach http://localhost:8545
Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - Invalid endpoint
 ~ $ geth attach ws://localhost:8545
Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - Invalid endpoint
```

How to attach geth to a local RPC on port 8545?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#Via Geth:

When you run your Parity node, use the `--geth` flag, for example, `parity --geth`.

Then go into another window and run `geth attach`.

The output of this is:

```
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!
>
```

The great thing about Parity is that you don't need to worry about turning on JSON-RPC, as it's on by default.

#Via Node:

Another approach is to use the NodeJS web3 library, which provides the same functionality. From [Parity Quick Start](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Quick-start):

```sh
npm install web3
node # Enter REPL
```

```js
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

Now you can interact with Parity the same as the Javascript Console:

```js
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(blockNumber => console.log(blockNumber)) // Regular Geth command, except connected to Parity
743397
```

Comment: Nice, `--geth` did the trick.

Comment: for web3 1.0.0 :  web3.eth.isSyncing().then(console.log)

Comment: most web3 command returns promises : so print callback res

Answer (score 8):

Recently released version 1.1 of Parity supports `modules/rpc_modules` RPC method and allows you to `geth attach <rpcaddress>` (geth 1.3.6 and 1.4.0 are supported).

Release details:
https://blog.ethcore.io/announcing-parity-1-1/

### Examples:

#### Geth 1.3.6

`$ geth attach rpc://localhost`

#### Geth 1.4.0

`$ geth attach http://localhost:8545`

Comment: Hum, Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - dial unix /home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused. Seems not ready yet.

Comment: You need to specify HTTP rpc endpoint:
`geth attach rpc://localhost` 1.3.6
or
`geth attach http://localhost:8545` 1.4.0

Comment: Feel free to use the [edit](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3573/edit) button to improve your answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Summary

I don't think that you will be able to connect `geth attach` (version 1.3.6) to `parity` (version Parity/v1.0.2-beta/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.7.0).

---

## Details

I tested using `geth attach` to connect to `parity --rpc` and I got the following message

```
Fatal: Unable to initialize console - Unable to parse module response - <nil>
```

So I did a trace using `tcpdump` and the results follow.

I started `parity` with the following options:

```
parity --datadir datadir --rpc --rpcapi "web3,eth,net,personal"  --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

I started `tcpdump` using the following command (meaning dump data in ASCII format on the interface `lo` (127.0.0.1) and port 8545):

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i lo port 8545
```

I started `geth` using the following command:

```
geth attach rpc:http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

And here are the results from `tcpdump` (tidied):

```
IP localhost.38186 > localhost.8545
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8545
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 57
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"modules","params":null}

localhost.8545 > localhost.38186
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 09:51:20 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept
Allow: OPTIONS, POST

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found","data":null},"id":1}
```

`geth` is asking `parity` for the support modules, but `parity` does not understand the "**modules**" command, so `geth` gives up.

I've tried using a few different options, but the results are similar.

I traced through the source code for `geth` and found that `cmd/geth/js.go` has a `welcome()` method that will request from the connected RPC instance what modules are supported. This is what you would normally see when you connect `geth attach` to `geth --rpc`:

```
    modules: db:1.0 eth:1.0 net:1.0 web3:1.0
```

But `parity` does not seem to support this JSON-RPC method.